# automatically add domain group to new windows installation

Tags: permissions, powershell, automation, desktop, windows-domain

I ran across the following catch22 in my workstation installation script while trying to automatically add a domain group to the local administrators.
The catch I’m experiencing is the following:

- When I’m using the local admin I have the rights to add users to a local group but need to provide domain credentials to connect to the domain
- When I’m using a domain user I can connect to the AD, but the user doing this is not yet a local admin so I can’t yet modify local groups.

I’m in a GMP environment so rules and regulations are !really! strict which limits other possible paths.

- Roles are split so I don’t have access to the domain admin.
- No changes are allowed to OU’s which could push the group from Group Policy
- Using PowerShell with remote scripts is not allowed

This is fairly easy to manually get around when using compmgmt.msc and provide the necessary credentials when asked … but I’d like to avoid adding manual steps and just automate the entire installation as much as possible.

A few details:

- The workstation's OS is Windows 10
- The script I'm using is PowerShell
- The script is running with a local admin account with elevated privileges
- The workstation is already joined to the domain
- The account used to join the workstation to the domain is not a domain admin
- To have admin rights with my domain account I need to add our department’s group to local admin group

The code I use to add a group to the local admin group is  
`$de = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Env:ComputerName/Administrators,group" 
$de.psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://MyCompanyDomain/MyDepartmentGroup").path)`
This code works like a charm when run with a domain account **and** is a local admin.

Since this is used for installation of a brand new workstation I can run this either as domain account **or** local admin.
With the former the `$de.psbase.Invoke("Add",` part fails
With the latter the `([ADSI]"WinNT://MyCompanyDomain/MyDepartmentGroup").path` fails

I tried using `start-process` cmdlet with `–verb runas` options to get a different security context but I ran into the same problem as above.

Is there any way I can

- only resolve `([ADSI]"WinNT://MyCompanyDomain/MyDepartmentGroup").path` in the security context of a domain user and pass that to the rest of my script running in the security context of the local admin (This is much the way compmgmt.msc does it)

or

- build the [ADSI] object from hardcoded data without the need to connect to the domain

or

- something else blindingly obvious I haven’t thought of

Comment: You can do this with unattend.xml, eliminating the need for any script. Is that feasible in your environment?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a domain group to a local group via the `unattend.xml` file, eliminating the need for any scripting.

### Editing Unattend.xml via System Image Manager (SIM)

After opening your `unattend.xml` in SIM, in the lower-left corner of the window, find the node for `Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup`. *(**Note:** You should use the node corresponding to your image's architecture, i.e., amd64 for 64-bit platforms.)* Expand the Shell-Setup node, then `UserAccounts`, `DomainAccounts`, and `DomainAccountList`. Right click the `DomainAccount` node, and choose to add the setting to pass 7 (oobeSystem).[image: adding DomainAccount node to unattend]

In the center of the SIM window, you need to configure the newly-added nodes. In the `DomainAccountList` node, enter the name of your domain in the `Domain` value.

In the `DomainAccount` node, the `Group` value should be set to the name of the local group you want to modify, in this case **Administrators**.
The `Name` value should be set to the name of the domain group that you want to add to the local group.

### Editing Unattend.xml Manually (*not recommended*)

You can also edit the `unattend.xml` file manually, in your favorite text editor. Locate the `<settings>` node for the **oobeSystem** pass. You can copy the `DomainAccounts` node below, and place it in your `unattend.xml` after the `AdministratorPassword` node. Be sure to modify the `Group` and `Name` nodes in the `DomainAccount` node, along with the domain name specified in the `Domain` node.

```
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" ... >
      <UserAccounts>
        <AdministratorPassword>
          <Value>mylocaladminpassword</Value>
          <PlainText>true</PlainText>
        </AdministratorPassword>
        <DomainAccounts>
          <DomainAccountList wcm:action="add">
            <DomainAccount wcm:action="add">
              <Group>Administrators</Group>
              <Name>Name-Of-Domain-Group-To-Add</Name>
            </DomainAccount>
            <Domain>DOMAIN_NAME_HERE</Domain>
          </DomainAccountList>
        </DomainAccounts>
```

Comment: This would indeed work on the condition I'm allowed to join the domain in the unattend.xml ... which unfortunately I'm not. The reason for this is (a) the password for automatic domain join cannot be encrypted in the unattend.xml, (b) our passwords need to be changed ever 6 months which would mean I need to create a new qualified build (read: lots of paperwork) every 6 months and (c) we're not allowed to use general service accounts, everything HAS to be named. Otherwise this is an excellent answer which (to be honest) I haven't thought of.

Comment: You should be able to use the above settings independent of whether you join the domain via unattend. Our domain join process is not in unattend either, and this method works for us.

Comment: In that case I'll give it a try and come back to this later (may take a few days). When you see your reply has been marked as answer you'll know what the outcome was ;) . edited to add: I'll have to find the equivalent in ICD though, not SIM. But if memory serves right I do remember something similar in there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you can share, but I work in a pretty open environment, and I'd be curious about processes you have to go through if you can share anything.

Comment: No big secret, just a heavily regulated environment. I’m currently doing a project in a ‘Big Pharma’ company. Government regulations enforces them to use GMP which stands for ‘Good Manufacturing Procedures’ … which is not without reason nicknamed ‘Great Mountains of Paper’. Extremely simplified this means that all actions that could in the slightest way impact production has to be documented, time stamped and signed. So a change to a customized build need to be documented and it needs to be logged who joined a PC to the AD. This results in the practice ‘If it works we don’t touch it, EVER!!!’